# If $S_i\cap S_{i+1}\ne \emptyset$ and $S_i$'s are connected sets, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}S_i$ is also connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Is the following statement about connected sets in metric space true?
**Statement:** Let $S_1,S_2,\cdots,S_n$ be connected sets such that $S_i\cap S_{i+1}\ne \emptyset$ for all $1\le i\le n-1$. Then $S=\bigcup_{i=1}^nS_i$ is connected.

**My attempt at proof:** Suppose $S$ is not connected. Then $\exists$ a proper subset $A$ of $S$ such that
\begin{align*}
S=A\sqcup A^c
\end{align*}
and $A$ is a clopen set. Let $p_i\in S_i\cup S_{i+1}$. Then $p_i$ must be either in $A$ or $A^c$. Let us WLOG assume that $p_1\in A$.
Then $S_1\cap A\ne \phi$ and $S_1\cap A$ is also clopen in $S_1$. Thus we must have $A \cap S_1=S_1$. Thus $S_1\subset A$. Because $p_1\in S_2$, similar reasoning shows that $S_2\subset A$.  Now because $p_3\in S_2\cap S_3$, this shows that $S_3\subset A$. Continuing this chain of reasoning, we get that $S_n\subset A$. Thus $S\subset A$, contradicting the fact that $A$ is a proper subset of $S$.

Does this same reasoning hold for topological spaces as well? (Seems like it should)

Comment: By induction on the number of sets in the union.

Comment: You are right. That gives an even shorter proof because we know that union of two connected sets with non-zero intersection is again connected.

Comment: Induction doesn’t allow you to conclude the infinite union is connected, unless you have another theorem.

Comment: The lemma you need for the induction proof is: If $T_1\subset T_2\subset\cdots$ is a sequence of connected spaces, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty T_i$ is connected. This is relatively easy to prove by contradiction.

Comment: No idea what that means. Is dice an autocorrect error? @OliverDíaz Induction doesn’t work to prove anything about infinite cases, without an additional argument for limit ordinals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Sorry, I wrote my first message to you on a mobile, big mistake. What I meant to say is that the induction argument work provided that the OP knows that as long as two sets are connected and have non-empty intersection, then their union is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\bigcup S_i$ has a clopen $U,$ then for each $i,$ either $S_i\subseteq U$ or $S_i\subseteq U^C.$

**Proof:** Otherwise, $S_i\cap U$ and $S_i\cap U^c$ are clopen in $S_i$ and nonempty, so $S_i$ is not connected.

---

Use this to prove by induction that if $S_1\subseteq U$ then all $S_i\subseteq U.$

Likewise, if $S_1\subseteq U^c$ then all $S_i\subseteq U^c.$

But this means either $U=S$ or $U=\emptyset,$ showing $S$ is connected.